# Calling a controller before index.jsp loads

Tags: java, html, jsp

I'm fairly new at JSP and I need some help.

I have an index.jsp file and obviously if you type "localhost//", it would automatically call the index.jsp by default. I was wondering how this works since I plan to call a controller first before the index.jsp loads.

I tried to work around it though. In my index.jsp, I put there something like:

```
 if(request.getParameter("submit") == null && 
    request.getAttribute("submit") == null){
    response.sendRedirect("getInformation"); 
 }
```

In here, I'm forcing the index.jsp to directly call my controller/servlet. (I used @WebServlet("/getInformation" on the controller I wanted to call).

I was wondering if there was a better way to do this since I would want all logical codes on my controller/servlet and all the html codes in .jsp as much as possible.

Comment: What do you want to do in that controller ? I guess you will get better approach if you share this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, this is the best approach. You can define your welcome files in the `web.xml`. Create a 'stupid' index.html setting a META tag redirecting to your controller, `SomeController` in the example below (delegates some computation from the server to the client):

**web.xml**

```
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

**index.html**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=./SomeController" />
<title>Some title</title>
</head>
<body>
If you are not automatically redirected please click <a href="./SomeController">here</a>.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks! Will try to do this.